# Xsd2code not working in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xsd, add-in

I am trying to use Xsd2Code but the addin does not show up when I right click an xsd file in the solution explorer. The installation goes smoothly without any glitch but still I am not able to see or use the addin  VS 2008. My OS is Vista x64.
  Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem. 2.8.1 installed without any errors yet it does not show up as right-click option. I can open the command window and run it from there just not through the gui.

Answer (score 0):

The install probably placed the file in a location that VS isn't looking in. There is an issue ticket mentioning this

http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=6988

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue running Visual Studio 2010 (SP1) under 64bit Windows 7 Enterprise (SP1).

The add-in would not show on the context menu or in the add-in manager.

I then uninstalled xsd2code from my computer and installed with Admin rights and the problem was fixed.

as 'Run as Admin' isn't available for MSI files, I started an Admin Command Prompt and ran the installer and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My environment Window7 - VS2010 SP1. After trying all possibilities, the simplest solution works for me
 - Find where xsd2code installs the Add in => Possible in c:\users[YourName]\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Addins or c:\Visual Studio 2010\Addins
 - In Visual Studio. Go to Tools->Options->Add-in/Macros Security->Add 
 - Find the path of AddIns and add to this option.
 - Restart your computer.
 - The "Run Xsd2Code generation" will be available when you right click on .Xsd